# Same url with two title in google search result

Tags: seo, google-search, google-search-console

"Mogral ಅಥವಾ മൊഗ്രാല്‍" was my website's (http://mogral.in) old title.
Since the title contains the words from another language, I felt it will badly affect the position in the search result.
So I changed to new title; contains only english words.

See this query; it shows old title:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Mogral+ಅಥವಾ+മൊഗ്രാല്‍

See this query it shows new title:
https://www.google.com/search?q=mogral+football+mappilapattu

Why it shows same url with two title?

One more problem is that google add the old titles to pages with malayalam-language titles
See https://www.google.com/search?q=site:mogral.in

I submitted the sitemap for all mogral.in/news/* only after changing the old title.

Why it is happening? how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question would be how long ago did you make the change? It takes time for any changes to be reflected in SERPs. Also, I don't see your site when I use your query examples - I see this post. So, the changes may be getting updated now. 
Finally,a sites title and meta tags are suggestions for google, not the rule. Google tries to improve CTR (click through rate) so many times for particular search terms, a modified version of your title and meta description will be displayed in the search results.